# Killing mom's heart with Judas not counting as an ending?

Tags: the-binding-of-isaac

I killed mom's heart with Isaac and got Judas and ending 1.  Then I killed her with Judas and completed the game with credits, but I don't see an additional ending.  Is it still counting as one of the 10 mom heart kills for unlocking it lives?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently not, having killed Mom's heart and restarting the game, did you earn "The Robo-Baby" achievement? If not, than I suppose it didn't register as a kill. If you DO have it, than I would make sure that you have the 'Transcendence' item in your collection if picked up or not.

Comment: i DID get the roobo-baby! that means that i only need to kill mom 8 times or it still not counts?

Comment: That means that it registered as a kill and it appears so. Although I would try to kill Mom's Heart with Isaac once more and see if the ending went to the 3rd or 2nd.

Comment: now i need to get lucky and actually **kill** her again XD tnx man

Comment: No problem. Glad to help. Good luck on killing mom once more. :p

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no special ending for Judas.  He is merely a different character that you can play, and does not influence the end of The Binding Of Isaac in any way.